# How do I get most of my standard Linux utilities and commands on Android 3.1?

Tags: linux, android

By standard, I mean just what users often get by default with one of the popular distros.

For example, `uname`, `finger`, `vim`, `tmux`, etc.

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android version 3.1, already rooted)

Also, I read somewhere about setting up a `chroot` on Android to run full-fledged Linux distros, such as Debian.
Is that possible?

Comment: For basic command line tools, get [Busybox](http://www.google.com/search?q=busybox+android) (I have no particular recommendation to make on the various Busybox providers for Android).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try Linux Installer ( https://market.android.com/details?id=com.galoula.LinuxInstall&feature=search_result ), which lets you install Debian or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

- Cross compile the tools you want.
- Use linux chroot on the device
- Use botbrew (search the play store)

But, before any option, install busybox with root perms.