# Install Ubuntu for Android

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

Canonical has an item on their site called Ubuntu for Android. This is a special distribution of Ubuntu which integrates with the Android system. Their website mentions that it is specifically targetted at manufacturers.

However, I would also like to install this, does anybody know if this is possible at all? and if so, how this can be done.

Comment: [`askubuntu.com` probably is the better venue for this, they even got a `ubuntu-for-android`-tag.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-for-android)

Comment: @sr_ Ubuntu questions are not off-topic here. That being said, I think bquast's question is already addressed on AU: [Ubuntu.sh on Android Phone](http://askubuntu.com/q/121229)

Comment: As far as I can see the link you provide is about a different Ubuntu on Android version. `Ubuntu for Linux` is a special distribution for android that is not run using virtualisation but uses the same kernel.

Comment: You can't ubuntu for android is an option to be included in the phones by manufacturers. As least that is what I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any publicly available distributions of Ubuntu for Android, but the idea must similar to installing a GNU/Linux distribution into a chroot, like here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20124/4319 .

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Ubuntu for Android has been halted by now or at least until Canonical finds a suitable partner to bring it to phones. Maybe we'll finally see this becoming a reality with the 64bit smartphones on the horizon.

Direct quote from Canonical:

> We still believe that U4A is a great product concept and that consumers would welcome the feature. The development within Ubuntu for U4A is complete. To take the development further requires a launch partner in order to make the necessary modifications on the Android side.
>
> We are currently not in concrete discussions with launch partners, but we are still very much open to such a partnership. We are focused on Ubuntu for Phones at the moment, therefore we are not actively pushing for Ubuntu for Android.However, if a prospective partner steps forward, we are very much open to launching Ubuntu for Android.

Reference: http://www.androidauthority.com/ubuntu-for-android-limbo-374454/

Additionally, there has not been a release of a publically available (test-)version.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @slm Thank you for your feedback. I changed my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this, it's appreciated!